# How to make drag and drop in vue without libraries?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to create drag and drop functionality for my app, without external libraries (just for practice). I have no idea where to start - i've already tried to make this with vuex, or external class to manage events. I can drag items and stuff, but I can't manipulate the data - I don't know how to get references to array or something in Vue instance.

For example, if I have external class, it looks like this:

```
export default class DragAndDrop {
  constructor() { // some code }
  init() {
     // add listeners to document
  }

  mousedownHandler() {
     // here i want to sort array of items which item I just clicked
     // but it is stored in Vue instance so I can't get access to it
  }  


  // other handlers
}
```

My try with vuex:

```
// store.js

state: {
  dragging: null
},
mutations: {
  // added this just for the full picture, nothing interesting
  setDragging(state, dragging) { // ... },
  move(state, {pageX, pageY}) { // ... }
},
actions: {
  drag(context, event) {
    // here is the same - I want to manipulate an array of items which item I dragging
    // change items order, sort, etc
  },
  move(context, event) {},
  mouseup(context, event) {}
}
```

```
// App.vue

<template lang="pug">
#app(@mousemove="move" @mouseup="mouseup")
    router-view
</template>
```

```
// Dragging.vue 

<template lang="pug">
.tasks
    .task-wrapper.draggable(
        v-for="task in tasks" 
        :key="task._id" 
        @click="openTaskModal(task._id)" // this event not firing because of @mousedown
        @mousedown="drag")

        .task {{ task.title }}
</template>
```

So now i can drag and drop items, but it is only visual effect. How to manipulate the data, use callbacks, etc? I really stucked in this and I will appreciate all suggestions :(

So, the questions, briefly: 
1. How I can get access to array of items which item I dragging? 
2. How to set multiple mouse events on item? (@mousedown and @click) 
3. Maybe I am in the wrong direction, so feel free to point me in the right one

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: @kip this is great, I've already read this. But how it can help me to integrate it to vue?

Comment: It's a bit complex. I can only give you a first hint, you need to start by adding `        draggable="true"
        @dragstart.stop="dragStartMethod"
        @dragenter.stop.prevent="dragEnterMethod"
        @dragover.stop.prevent
        @dragleave.stop.prevent="dragLeaveMethod"
        @drop.prevent.stop="droppedMethod"` to all your draggable components. Hope this will help you at least a little bit.

Comment: There is a great short course where Damian Dulisz aka @shentao (Vue core team member)  shows how to do it: https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/watch-us-build-trello-clone/building-our-board